# Ubuntu PHP Laravel write log into file

Tags: php, laravel

I have Ubuntu 18.04 and Laravel.
In post method - upload file, I want to save parameters from upload files. At the begin I try to save something in the file:

```
public function settingsEdit($parameter)
{
        file_put_contents('/tmp/aa.log', 'll');

        return view('pages.account.settings.edit', ['user' => $this->user(), 'parameter' => $parameter]);
}
```

There is no error, but file isn't created. In tmp directory doesn't exists file aa.log.

Comment: Or even use the logging system : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/logging

Comment: You may want to consider adding some error handling around the `file_put_contents()` call. According to the docs: _"This function returns the number of bytes that were written to the file, or `FALSE` on failure."_ You should consider reading the value returned by `file_put_contents()` to ensure you are not receiving an error. For example: `if(FALSE === file_put_contents('/tmp/aa.log', '11')) { exit("Error writing file!"); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using laravel, so you can do `Storage::put('/tmp/aa.log', '11');` and you're file will be created in the storage folder, which is the default file location in Laravel.

Or maybe try to use https://github.com/rap2hpoutre/laravel-log-viewer package which create one log file every day.